# Android change image when device rotates

Tags: android, android-studio

**I need a simple method of changing image if the device is rotated horizontally**

I have my background set for my main activity but I want the image to fit when the device is tilted.  I want to just change the image to a wide version.  How do I change on device rotation?

Comment: dont put a fixed width and height of your ImageView in your xml

Comment: you need to override on configurationChange method of your activity then check if screen orientation is horizontal if yes then do what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your portrait background image in here:

```
src/main/res/drawable
```

And put your landscape background image in here:

```
src/main/res/drawable-land
```

If they have the same name (and therefore the same resource ID), Android will automatically take care of placing the correct one in the correct situation.

All resources can be automatically selected like this by the current device configuration.  [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: Thanks so much @Doug Stevenson! Saved me doing unnecessary work.